# Vimeo video uploading through Laravel giving -file_put_contents():Write of --- bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to upload a video on Vimeo using Laravel.
I have successfully installed **SDK** and have established connection to vimeo.
However when I am trying to upload a video using-

```
 use Vimeo\Laravel\VimeoManager;
 use Vimeo\Laravel\Facades\Vimeo;

    public function teacherlessonAdd(Request $request,VimeoManager $vimeo)
   {
       $file_name=$request->file('lesson_video');
       $uri=$vimeo->upload($file_name,array(
        'name' => $request->name,
        'description' => $request->description,
      ));
      dd($uri);
   }
```

The page loads and the I get the error:

**file_put_contents(): Write of 211 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied**

Although a file of 0 mb is getting uploaded at vimeo panel.

I am on localhost and have tried

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus protection.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Github issues page: https://github.com/vimeo/laravel/issues/77

Where I found the following answer:

> I also face this issue but solve it with this simple step.
>
> ```
> go into vendor/ folder.
> chmod -R 775 ankitpokhrel/
> chown -R www-data ankitpokhrel/
> ```